# createAsyncThunk и преобразование данных

Tags: javascript, redux, fetch

Всем привет!
Помогите, пожалуйста, никак не получается: делаю проект с News API и внедряю redux toolkit. Возникла такая проблема: мне нужно получить статьи и после преобразовать их (вытащить только нужные поля полученного объекта). Подскажите, в каком месте я могу это сделать?

Слайс пока выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы правда думаете, что приложить код скриншотом - хорошая идея?

Comment: Чисто технически, это можно сделать практически в любом месте, откуда можно достать данные, однако, если у вас есть копмонент, который данные получает, то пусть он же и фильтрует данные, а отдает готовый набор.

Comment: @T0xee.n17 почему скриншот это плохо?

Comment: @Margarita тому кто захочет проверить/дополнить/вставить в ответ ваш код придётся вручную перепечатывать его с картинки. Заниматься этим никто не будет, поэтому на StackOverflow принято прикладывать код в виде текста, а не скриншота.

Comment: @T0xee.n17 поняла, спасибо!)